# how to programmatically check if a context is active

Tags: 7

I am reading through the API of the drupal 7 context module, and searching for examples, but I can't find a working example of how to programmatically test if a context is active for the current page.

I tried to call the context_isset() function defined in context.module, but what are the namespace and the attribute values? I only know about the context name and it's tag.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What can be done is to use the context_active_contexts() function.

Sample code, to see if the is_iframe context is active for the current page:

```
$contexts = context_active_contexts();
if (array_key_exists('is_iframe', $contexts)) : 
    watchdog('te','context is_iframe is set');
endif;
```