# How to find which content type is using which context?

Tags: 7, nodes

How to find which content type (`abc`) is using which context? As I do have around 30 contexts in my site.

Is there a way to find which context is using content type (`abc`)?

Comment: like this you can log the used contexts: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/81008/how-to-programmatically-check-if-a-context-is-active

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the code of the page? All the contexts should use a unique class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some module suggestions that may help get you closer to find the exact answer to your question:

- ## Context Inspector block provided by the Devel module

  If you use the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module you'll have a "Context Inspector" block. You can place that block in a region on a page and then see the current contexts output via Krumho.
- ## Devel Catcher module

  To enhance your "debugging" experience (hm, hm ...), there is also the [Devel Catcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_catcher) module, which has [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) as a module dependency.

  Here is an excerpt from its project page (why you may want to consider this module):

  > ... aggregates or "catches" all development debug info into one easy to access place.
  >
  > Similar in style to Firebug or Chrome's Inspector. Devel Catcher intercepts common debug info into a tabbed interface as opposed to having to assign debug blocks to a region or dumping the output at the end of your HTML document.
  >
  > Currently Devel Catcher can catch the query log from the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module, node access rules from the Devel Node Access module and the context inspector block from the Context UI module.

So by using (repeating) this approach for a page of each of your content types, you might be able to find out which content type is using which context, no?

Comment: great to see the Devel Catcher module, I am not at all aware of that. This module make sense to me.

Comment: After you ever had some time to experiment with it, I'd be interested in some type of feedback (via an extra comment) about it ...

Answer (score 1):

May be it helps someone.

```
$active_contexts = array_keys(context_active_contexts());
foreach($active_contexts as $active_context) {
  print $active_context;
}
```